# Rails routes: GET method redirecting to show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, module, routes

I have simple controller and routes file. 
In my route and controller i have created a module. I wrote a simple method which is redirecting me show. I am not sure why.

**Controller**

```
  module Seller
    class CampaignsController < Seller::BaseController

      before_action :confirm_logged_in

      def viewAllCampaigns
       @campaigns = Campaign.all

      end

      def show
      end

    end

  end
```

**Routes file**

```
 scope module: 'seller' do
   #namespace :power do
   resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
   resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
   resources :campaigns, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy]   
   get 'viewAllCampaigns' => 'campaigns#viewAllCampaigns'   
 end
```

**Output**

```
Started GET "/campaigns/viewAllCampaigns" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-12 17:39:43 +0500
  Processing by Seller::CampaignsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"viewAllCampaigns"}
  Rendered seller/campaigns/show.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

I am hitting http://localhost:3000/campaigns/viewAllCampaigns in browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally your `routes` should be defined like this.

```
resources :campaigns, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy] do  
   get 'viewAllCampaigns', on: :collection   
end
```

The first comment on the `routes.rb` file is `The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.` This is the reason your route is redirecting to `show`. Rails is treating this url as `campain/:id`.

Comment: I tried this one too and it look like a better approch.. I am going with this one and it worked. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Routes are tested in order, from top to bottom.  The `show` route you've added for the `campaigns` resource will look for urls matching this pattern:

```
/campaigns/:id
```

`/campaigns/viewAllCampaigns` matches this, so it will do the `show` action., with `params[:id]` = "viewAllCampaigns"

Move the special case route up above the `resources#campaigns` route to fix this, then it will catch the url first.

```
get 'viewAllCampaigns' => 'campaigns#viewAllCampaigns'   
resources :campaigns, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the following get request as a show action because show expects campaigns/:id, and it assumes 'viewAllCampaigns' is an id in this instance:

```
/campaigns/viewAllCampaigns
```

Your link_to should just be pointing to the following:

```
'/viewAllCampaigns'
```

Your route structure isn't really RESTful, but that's a separate topic.